# #<ActiveRecord::AssociationRelation Active Record Query Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Further Updated

my tags table

```
  create_table "tags", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "category"
    t.string   "name"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end
```

**Updated**

Turns out I am getting the tags but not the pictures where its tags equal this value

```
@pics   
#<ActiveRecord::AssociationRelation [#<Tag id: 3, category: "Length", name: "stupid", created_at: "2014-09-12 17:18:44", updated_at: "2014-09-12 17:18:44">]>
```

### the above is from better errors

I am going through tags that belong to a particular user in the view

```
<% user.tags.each do |tag| %>
                <li><%= link_to tag.name, user_path(user.url_name, user, tag_name: tag.name) %></li>
              <% end %>
```

From checking my server log I am getting the value in `tag_name` successfully passed to the `user_path`

server log

```
Processing by UsersController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"tag_name"=>"brown", "name"=>"Judy ", "id"=>"8"}
```

The tag name is brown for the example above.

here is my users controller show method that process that tag_name

```
  def show
    @user = User.find params[:id]
    if params[:tag_name] #my attempt
      tag = params[:tag_name] #my attempt
      @user.pics.each do |pic| #mine
        @pics = pic.tags.where(name: tag) #mine
      end #mine
    else
      @pics = @user.pics.page(params[:page]).per(20) #original
  end
```

if an user clicks on a tag then the list of pictures who only has that tag connected to it gets shown.

the show view looks something like this

```
<% @pics.each do |i| %>
  <div class="two-col inline-element">
    <div class="col-md-12 white-container no-padding">
      <%= link_to image_tag(i.picture.re_sized.url, alt: i.title), pic_path(i) %>
      <div class="tag1">
        Tags:
        <% i.tags.each do |tag| %>
          <%= tag.name%>
        <% end %>
      </div>
```

I am currently getting `undefined method picture for #<Tag:0x007f96e0829438>` which means `@pic` has nothing

This in rails console did come up with something.

```
User.last.pics.each do |pic| pic.tags.where(name: "stupid") end

 => [#<Pic id: 6, picture: "c19862b844b58ecbce39_110785.png", user_id: 8, title: "hh", caption: "hh", created_at: "2014-09-12 22:13:17", updated_at: "2014-09-12 22:13:17", hidden: nil>, #<Pic id: 5, picture: "d9c1b59d76ea44f0d1c7_110787.jpg", user_id: 8, title: "TestPic2", caption: "TestPic2", created_at: "2014-09-12 21:30:03", updated_at: "2014-09-12 21:30:03", hidden: nil>, #<Pic id: 4, picture: "90798f6c29618066a239_111061.jpg", user_id: 8, title: "TestPic", caption: "TestPic", created_at: "2014-09-12 21:25:34", updated_at: "2014-09-12 21:25:34", hidden: nil>]
```

thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're over thinking the whole thing, your show method could be simplified a lot

```
def show
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  @pics = params[:tag_name].present? ? 
    @user.pics.joins(:tags).where(tags: {name: params[:tag_name]}) :
    @user.pics 
end #add your pagination
```

Comment: your way is throwing this error  `@user.pics.where(tag: {name: "brown"} )  
!! #<ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'tag.name' in 'where clause': SELECT `pics`.* FROM `pics`  WHERE (`pics`.`hidden` IS NULL OR `pics`.`hidden` = 0) AND `pics`.`user_id` = 32 AND `tag`.`name` = 'brown'  ORDER BY `pics`.`id` DESC>`

Comment: yea my bad, it should be `tags` not `tag`